# I'm trying to find the Top 5 results of SQL Query but getting an error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Top 5* 
FROM (
select
    SUM(CASE WHEN Medal = 'Gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Gold_Medals',
    Country_Code
from olympic_medals
GROUP BY Country_Code
ORDER BY Gold_Medals DESC)
```

ERROR:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
> tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
> or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Skip the sub-query, and it will work

Comment: Also, the ORDER BY _inside_ a subquery isn't guaranteed to be kept outside it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a subquery

```
select top 5 SUM(CASE WHEN Medal = 'Gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Gold_Medals',
       Country_Code
from olympic_medals
GROUP BY Country_Code
ORDER BY Gold_Medals DESC
```